# How to create a efficent linestring out of geography points using postgis

Tags: postgis, kml, point, geojson, linestring

I'm trying to create a linestring out of geography points. At the moment I'm doing it like this:

```
select ST_GeographyFromText(ST_Makeline(a.record_point)) from (
select (record_point::geometry)
from records order by record_timestamp) a
```

Problem is that most points have unnecessary decimal places (6 is sufficient) and some points are exactly the same. I can set the decimal place precision when converting to KML but is there another way to do this and how to get rid of overlapping points?

**My own solution:**
It is PostgreSQL specific because of the window function. Basically I just leave out spatially equal sequential geometry points and reduce the precision with geojson converter (kml converter has the same option).

```
select st_asgeojson(ST_MakeLine(points.record_point),6) from (
select (record_point)::geometry as record_point
lag( (record_point)::geometry, 1) over w as prev_point,
from records 
window w as (order by record_id)
order by record_timestamp
) points where not st_equals(record_point, prev_point)
```

Answer (score 2):

PostGIS has a "cleangeometry()" function which I believe works like SpatiaLite's "SanitizeGeometry()".

My mantra is that there is never a single solution in GIS, so here's two other off-beat approachs:

1. If you have multiple lines you could pack them all in a multilinestring and use the ST_LineMerge function.  It will kill the duplicates and join the lines efficiently.  You could then explode the multilinestring
2. You could simplify the geometery with a small tolerance.  Simple and effective :)

Comment: cleangeometry() [link](http://postgis.refractions.net/pipermail/postgis-users/2008-September/021097.html) didnt work for me, its output was multilinestring, which made result even bigger in size. I think its because it uses st_union function internally. I posted my solution under my question.

Answer (score 2):

If an 'efficient geometry' means removing nodes on a polyline that are unnecessary to define the shape, use PostGIS's [ST_Simplify](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Simplify.html) . It uses the Douglas-Peucker algorithm to thin nodes. You've got some control over how 'simplified' you get.

```
SELECT ST_Simplify( ST_GeographyFromText(ST_Makeline(a.record_point)), 100 ) as the_geom FROM...
```

And lastly, since you're storing your result as a record with a geometry data type, you don't care how many decimal points you carry. You can reduce the precision of your exported geometry later, if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not forget that you are still inside a RELATIONAL with geography database.

One way to eliminate duplicated rows( in this case points ) is to append the group by operator.
You can also use the postgresql good distinct on clause.

To remove point precision you can snap vertices to desired precision. I put a chaned query below. Fell free to fix any mistakes I could have maded during the typing.

```
-- assume a projection with meter units --
SELECT ST_GeographyFromText( ST_Makeline( ST_snapToGrid( a.record_point, 0.01 ) ) )
FROM
(
  SELECT (record_point::geometry)
  FROM records
  GROUP BY (record_point::geometry)
  ORDER BY record_timestamp
) a
```

I also confirm that the cleanGeometry routine did not worked on several cases reported by clients. His use is not necessary with the new postgis 2.